# ListView Not Updating When ItemsSource Changed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've done a lot of reading on this, but I'm evidently still missing something.  I could work around it by passing in an ObservableCollection to the class constructor but I want to understand why it's failing.    There is nothing in the output window indicating a broken binding.  A Visibility Converter I have on the ObservableCollection<> property works fine.  Here is the XAML.  the problem is with the DetailsListBox

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="2" >
    <Label 
        Name="DetailsLabel" Foreground="Black"  Height="20" Width="Auto" 
        FontSize="8"
        Content="{Binding Description, Converter={StaticResource DetailConverter}}"
        Visibility="{Binding Path=DetailsList, Converter={StaticResource DetailsVisConverter}}"
        Background="Transparent"
        Margin="0" Padding="0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    </Label>
    <ListBox 
        Name="DetailsList" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DetailsList}"
        Visibility="{Binding Path=DetailsList, Converter={StaticResource DetailsVisConverter}}" 
        >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Content="{Binding Path=.}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Here is the code-behind creating the class instance and setting up the ObservableCollection:

```
    NodeAsThumb hosthumb = CreateClusterNodeAsThumb(host);
    hosthumb.DataContext = hosthumb;
    ObservableCollection<string> PortDetails = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    foreach (PortResult pr in hostports) { PortDetails.Add(pr.Interface); }
    hosthumb.DetailsList = PortDetails;
```

Here is some of the class definition, including the PropertyChanged handler. OnPropertyChanged is getting called.  I originally had DetailsList as a List<>, but read it should be an ObservableCollection<> as it would fire the ICollectionChanged, but that doesn't appear to be happening.

```
public  class NodeAsThumb :FabricThumb, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private ObservableCollection<string> _detailsList = null;
    public ObservableCollection<string> DetailsList { get { return _detailsList; } set { _detailsList = value; OnPropertychanged("DetailsList"); } }


  // I have verified that this gets fired when DetailsList is assigned to
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    private void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, e);
    }


    private void OnPropertychanged(string propertyName)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

Lastly, the VisiblityConverter that does work, and is also bound to DetailsList.  When it is null, I want it hidden. I thought it might be the VisibilityConverter still having it collapsed, so I disabled it but ended up with an always empty list.

```
public class DetailsListVisiblityConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public Object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }

    public Object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Here is the output window after setting the TraceLevel to High:

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 : Created BindingExpression  (hash=1635228) for Binding (hash=30787047)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 :   Path: 'DetailsList'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=1635228): Default mode resolved to OneWay
System.Windows.Data Warning: 61 : BindingExpression (hash=1635228): Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
System.Windows.Data Warning: 62 : BindingExpression (hash=1635228): Attach to System.Windows.Controls.ListBox.ItemsSource (hash=59834015)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=1635228): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=1635228): Found data context element: ListBox (hash=59834015) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 71 : BindingExpression (hash=1635228): DataContext is null
System.Windows.Data Warning: 65 : BindingExpression (hash=1635228): Resolve source deferred
System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 : Created BindingExpression (hash=61434729) for Binding (hash=30787047)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 :   Path: 'DetailsList'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=61434729): Default mode resolved to OneWay
System.Windows.Data Warning: 61 : BindingExpression (hash=61434729): Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
System.Windows.Data Warning: 62 : BindingExpression (hash=61434729): Attach to System.Windows.Controls.ListBox.ItemsSource (hash=51565323)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=61434729): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=61434729): Found data context element: ListBox (hash=51565323) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 71 : BindingExpression (hash=61434729): DataContext is null
System.Windows.Data Warning: 65 : BindingExpression (hash=61434729): Resolve source deferred
System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 : Created BindingExpression (hash=27129916) for Binding (hash=30787047)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 :   Path: 'DetailsList'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=27129916): Default mode resolved to OneWay
System.Windows.Data Warning: 61 : BindingExpression (hash=27129916): Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
System.Windows.Data Warning: 62 : BindingExpression (hash=27129916): Attach to System.Windows.Controls.ListBox.ItemsSource (hash=40297137)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=27129916): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=27129916): Found data context element: ListBox (hash=40297137) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 71 : BindingExpression (hash=27129916): DataContext is null
System.Windows.Data Warning: 65 : BindingExpression (hash=27129916): Resolve source deferred
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=1635228): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=1635228): Found data context element: ListBox (hash=59834015) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=1635228): Activate with root item NodeAsThumb (hash=46479497)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 107 : BindingExpression (hash=1635228):   At level 0 using cached accessor for NodeAsThumb.DetailsList: RuntimePropertyInfo(DetailsList)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=1635228): Replace item at level 0 with NodeAsThumb (hash=46479497), using accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(DetailsList)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=1635228): GetValue at level 0 from NodeAsThumb (hash=46479497) using RuntimePropertyInfo(DetailsList): <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=1635228): TransferValue - got raw value <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=1635228): TransferValue - using final value <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=61434729): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=61434729): Found data context element: ListBox (hash=51565323) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=61434729): Activate with root item NodeAsThumb (hash=1807185)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 107 : BindingExpression (hash=61434729):   At level 0 using cached accessor for NodeAsThumb.DetailsList: RuntimePropertyInfo(DetailsList)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=61434729): Replace item at level 0 with NodeAsThumb (hash=1807185), using accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(DetailsList)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=61434729): GetValue at level 0 from NodeAsThumb (hash=1807185) using RuntimePropertyInfo(DetailsList): <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=61434729): TransferValue - got raw value <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=61434729): TransferValue - using final value <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=27129916): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=27129916): Found data context element: ListBox (hash=40297137) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=27129916): Activate with root item NodeAsThumb (hash=22613965)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 107 : BindingExpression (hash=27129916):   At level 0 using cached accessor for NodeAsThumb.DetailsList: RuntimePropertyInfo(DetailsList)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=27129916): Replace item at level 0 with NodeAsThumb (hash=22613965), using accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(DetailsList)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=27129916): GetValue at level 0 from NodeAsThumb (hash=22613965) using RuntimePropertyInfo(DetailsList): <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=27129916): TransferValue - got raw value <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=27129916): TransferValue - using final value <null>
'FabricAnalyzer.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: FabricAnalyzer.exe): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework-SystemCore\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\PresentationFramework-SystemCore.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 : Created BindingExpression (hash=63575268) for Binding (hash=22674843)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 :   Path: 'DetailsList'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=63575268): Default mode resolved to OneWay
System.Windows.Data Warning: 61 : BindingExpression (hash=63575268): Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
System.Windows.Data Warning: 62 : BindingExpression (hash=63575268): Attach to System.Windows.Controls.ListBox.ItemsSource (hash=66716242)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=63575268): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=63575268): Found data context element: ListBox (hash=66716242) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 71 : BindingExpression (hash=63575268): DataContext is null
System.Windows.Data Warning: 65 : BindingExpression (hash=63575268): Resolve source deferred
System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 : Created BindingExpression (hash=55244468) for Binding (hash=22674843)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 :   Path: 'DetailsList'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=55244468): Default mode resolved to OneWay
System.Windows.Data Warning: 61 : BindingExpression (hash=55244468): Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
System.Windows.Data Warning: 62 : BindingExpression (hash=55244468): Attach to System.Windows.Controls.ListBox.ItemsSource (hash=28507895)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=55244468): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=55244468): Found data context element: ListBox (hash=28507895) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 71 : BindingExpression (hash=55244468): DataContext is null
System.Windows.Data Warning: 65 : BindingExpression (hash=55244468): Resolve source deferred
System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 : Created BindingExpression (hash=53268321) for Binding (hash=22674843)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 :   Path: 'DetailsList'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=53268321): Default mode resolved to OneWay
System.Windows.Data Warning: 61 : BindingExpression (hash=53268321): Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
System.Windows.Data Warning: 62 : BindingExpression (hash=53268321): Attach to System.Windows.Controls.ListBox.ItemsSource (hash=20831783)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=53268321): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=53268321): Found data context element: ListBox (hash=20831783) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 71 : BindingExpression (hash=53268321): DataContext is null
System.Windows.Data Warning: 65 : BindingExpression (hash=53268321): Resolve source deferred
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=63575268): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=63575268): Found data context element: ListBox (hash=66716242) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=63575268): Activate with root item NodeAsThumb (hash=19140135)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 107 : BindingExpression (hash=63575268):   At level 0 using cached accessor for NodeAsThumb.DetailsList: RuntimePropertyInfo(DetailsList)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=63575268): Replace item at level 0 with NodeAsThumb (hash=19140135), using accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(DetailsList)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=63575268): GetValue at level 0 from NodeAsThumb (hash=19140135) using RuntimePropertyInfo(DetailsList): <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=63575268): TransferValue - got raw value <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=63575268): TransferValue - using final value <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=55244468): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=55244468): Found data context element: ListBox (hash=28507895) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=55244468): Activate with root item NodeAsThumb (hash=31430389)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 107 : BindingExpression (hash=55244468):   At level 0 using cached accessor for NodeAsThumb.DetailsList: RuntimePropertyInfo(DetailsList)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=55244468): Replace item at level 0 with NodeAsThumb (hash=31430389), using accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(DetailsList)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=55244468): GetValue at level 0 from NodeAsThumb (hash=31430389) using RuntimePropertyInfo(DetailsList): <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=55244468): TransferValue - got raw value <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=55244468): TransferValue - using final value <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=53268321): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=53268321): Found data context element: ListBox (hash=20831783) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=53268321): Activate with root item NodeAsThumb (hash=35867003)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 107 : BindingExpression (hash=53268321):   At level 0 using cached accessor for NodeAsThumb.DetailsList: RuntimePropertyInfo(DetailsList)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=53268321): Replace item at level 0 with NodeAsThumb (hash=35867003), using accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(DetailsList)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=53268321): GetValue at level 0 from NodeAsThumb (hash=35867003) using RuntimePropertyInfo(DetailsList): <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=53268321): TransferValue - got raw value <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=53268321): TransferValue - using final value <null>
System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=WWPN; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridTextColumn' (HashCode=30423852); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=SwitchName; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridTextColumn' (HashCode=33040847); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=WWPN; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridTextColumn' (HashCode=19299281); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=SwitchName; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridTextColumn' (HashCode=47325326); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
```

Comment: Did you verify that the in-memory actually *has* items? As in; `hostports` is not an empty collection? The `= delegate` on PropertyChanged is really weird too

Comment: Is the ListBox the ListView you're referring to? What is `NodeAsThumb`?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET hostports is not empty.  I use it for other things.

Comment: @EdPlunkett yes the ListBox is the ListView I'm referring to. NodeAsThumb is a class I wrote that inherits the MDSN Thumb class.  I use it to draw a computer network diagram.  I have a couple different derived Thumb classes.

Comment: What do you see in the VS output pane at runtime if you make this change to the ItemsSource binding? `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DetailsList, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"`

Comment: @EdPlunkett I added all the output to the question, it would be too long for a comment.

Comment: @DavidGreen Well, it looks like it's getting whatever's in DetailsList. Hm.

Comment: @EdPlunkett  I believe this error is the problem: "Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element"  it's not getting the data context set properly

Comment: OK, I was trying to look at your trace output on my phone, with predictable results. Now I'm at my desk and I reformatted it with Ctrl+K -- and I see what you mean. So: Is `NodeAsThumb` being used in the template for a `DataGridTextColumn`? If not, those "governing FrameworkElement" errors are from something else.

Comment: What happens if you move `hosthumb.DataContext = hosthumb;` to after the initialization of `hosthumb.DetailsList`? Also, please remove the initializer  `= delegate { }` from your `PropertyChanged` event, then put a breakpoint in `OnPropertyChanged` and confirm that somebody really is handling the event.

Comment: Your XAML for `NodeAsThumb`: Is that in a `ControlTemplate` for `NodeAsThumb`, or what?

Comment: You haven't provided anything like enough code to reproduce what's happening. Now it turns out you're doing some bizarre stunt where the window gives these things their control templates for some reason. I'm out, good luck. Next time, make your controls controls, make their properties dependency properties, template them normally, put them in the UI in a normal way, and if anything *does* go wrong -- which will be less likely -- people will be more able to help you figure out what happened.

Answer (score 1):

I would not bind an `ObservableCollection` and reinitialize it. Even with `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `OnPropertyChanged`.

Please just `Clear()` your `ObservableCollection` and use a `Property` like `Count` to apply `Visibility`.

```
public class MyClass : BaseViewModel
{
    public System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string> MyCollection
    {
        get;
    }


    public MyClass()
    {
        MyCollection = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string>();
        MyCollection.CollectionChanged += MyCollection_CollectionChanged;
    }

    public bool IsEmpty
    {
        get
        {
            return MyCollection.Count == 0;
        }
    }

    public void RefillMyCollection(IEnumerable<string> values)
    {
        MyCollection.Clear();
        foreach(string value in values)
        {
            MyCollection.Add(value);
        }
    }


    private void MyCollection_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("IsEmpty");
    }


}
```

You will need another `IValueConverter`, but u have so many possibilitys. Like `IsEmpty`, `Count`, `HasItems`. I think you get the idea.

Comment: I like the new C# syntax for readonly properties for this, it *really* helps you from accidentally swapping out the collection reference. `public System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string> MyCollection {get;}`. Now the *only* place that the actual collection reference can be set is once, in the constructor. It forces you to handle modifying the collection in the correct way.

Comment: The `private set` still allows the reference to be swapped out from within the class.  You can use that syntax without the `private set` to get the same effect (in the latest c# version) with the safety of not allowing a new instance to be swapped in.